# Pandas merge function: sometimes a value to merge on misses, how to handle?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I have one file with drivers' ID's and the trips they made (from a specific subset of all drivers: persons who followed a specific training) and another file with data about the last minutes of driving from all trips. The files look like this, for example:

Information about the drivers' trips

```
trip_drivers.csv
driver_id, vehicle_id, departure_date, trip_id, from, to, arrival_date  

0001, A1, 03032015, 427, Rotterdam, Amsterdam, 03032015  
0002, A2, 03032015, 428, Amsterdam, Rotterdam, 03032015
```

By the way, trip_id is not a unique id for each trip. Rotterdam-Amsterdam always has trip ID 427, for example.

And the last few minutes of driving:

```
trip_data.csv  
timestamp, vehicle_id, arrival_date, trip_id, from, to, speed, ...  

0, A1, 03032015, 427, Rotterdam, Amsterdam, 40, ...  
1, A1, 03032015, 427, Rotterdam, Amsterdam, 42, ...  
2, A1, 03032015, 427, Rotterdam, Amsterdam, 41, ...
```

As you can see, the driver_id is present in the first file, but it isn't present in the second file. I want to merge these files in such a way that the driver_id from the first file is appended to each line in the second file.

However, not all trip data relates to a driver in that specific subset. I tried the following:

```
merged = pd.merge(tripdata, drivers, on=['vehicle_id', 'from', 'to', 'arrival_date'])
```

But that leaves trips that were not performed by one of the drivers in the subset out.

When trying an outer merge:

```
merged = pd.merge(tripdata, drivers, on=['Tail', 'Dep', 'Dest', 'Month', 'Day'], how='outer')
```

This appends the matched trips at the end of the file and copies the data it merges on. This leaves me with a bunch of lines like this at the end of the merged file:

> ,,A1,03032015,,Rotterdam,Amsterdam,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0001

What is the correct way to merge these files?

Comment: I guess you want to use `how='left'`in this case

Comment: Unfortunately, this leaves all data from trip_data.csv as it is, adds the driver_id column on the right - but ID's are not filled in.

Comment: Are you after `rhs.combine_first(lhs)`?

Comment: @LaurensJansma, it works for me - see my the output in my answer

Comment: It's also not clear why do you have two different joining conditions (two different sets of columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `how='left'`:

```
import six
import pandas as pd

data = """\
driver_id, vehicle_id, departure_date, trip_id, from, to, arrival_date
0001, A1, 03032015, 427, Rotterdam, Amsterdam, 03032015
0002, A2, 03032015, 428, Amsterdam, Rotterdam, 03032015
"""

drv = pd.read_csv(six.StringIO(data), skipinitialspace=True)
print(drv)

data = """\
timestamp, vehicle_id, arrival_date, trip_id, from, to, speed
0, A1, 03032015, 427, Rotterdam, Amsterdam, 40
1, A1, 03032015, 427, Rotterdam, Amsterdam, 42
2, A1, 03032015, 427, Rotterdam, Amsterdam, 41
"""
trip = pd.read_csv(six.StringIO(data), skipinitialspace=True)
print(trip)

merged = pd.merge(trip, drv, on=['vehicle_id', 'from', 'to', 'arrival_date'], how='left')
print('{:-^60}'.format('merged'))
print(merged[['driver_id', 'vehicle_id', 'speed']])
```

Output:

```
   driver_id vehicle_id  departure_date  trip_id       from         to  \
0          1         A1         3032015      427  Rotterdam  Amsterdam
1          2         A2         3032015      428  Amsterdam  Rotterdam

   arrival_date
0       3032015
1       3032015
   timestamp vehicle_id  arrival_date  trip_id       from         to  speed
0          0         A1       3032015      427  Rotterdam  Amsterdam     40
1          1         A1       3032015      427  Rotterdam  Amsterdam     42
2          2         A1       3032015      427  Rotterdam  Amsterdam     41
---------------------------merged---------------------------
   driver_id vehicle_id  speed
0          1         A1     40
1          1         A1     42
2          1         A1     41
```

Comment: It's strange how this appears to work for this example, but when applying it to the complete dataset, the driver_id is returned as NaN in the merged file...

Comment: I added a column 'test' filled with the number 1234 in the original datafile. This one also changes to a 'NaN' after merging.

Comment: can you update you input sample with that column so we could reproduce your issue?